# Serial available always returns 0 in Arduino

Tags: arduino

Why do I keep getting 0? I tried several ways and took the sample code on the Arduino site, but that didn’t work either. I always get `Serial.available() = 0`.

```
int incomingByte = 0;  // For incoming serial data

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);  // Opens serial port, sets data rate to 9600 bit/s
}

void loop() {

    // Send data only when you receive data:
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
        // Read the incoming byte:
        incomingByte = Serial.read();

        // Say what you got:
        Serial.print("I received: ");
        Serial.println(incomingByte, DEC);
    }
    else
        Serial.print("I received nothing ");
}
```

Comment: What's the hardware setup?  Are you confident you haven't switched RX/TX lines?  That your sender doesn't have flow control (hardware or software) enabled?

Comment: Im sure it is correct. Am I suppose to check somewhere on my com ports? No idea. I also unplugged the board and restarted arduino IDE. Nothing.

Comment: So I have the same problem: if(Serial.available()){digitalWrite(led, HIGH)} else {digitalWrite(led, LOW)}} I begin.serial but serial.available never evaluates to be true. What is the cause of this? I looked at all other relating posts and there doesn't appear to be much information. I will be trying the same code on a new UNO R3 soon to see if it's the Nano I have is just being unresponsive as I'm starting to think it's hardware related issue.

Comment: How do you send data to the serial input?

Answer (score 2):

Your program works fine on my Arduino although you need some delays to stop the rapid-fire "I received nothing " messages.  I would change the "I received nothing " block to include a delay of a few seconds e.g. delay(3000) for a 3-second delay.

Also, consider changing your code to use a SerialEvent() procedure such as depicted here: [SerialEvent example](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SerialEvent)

```
String inputString = "";         // a string to hold incoming data
boolean stringComplete = false;  // whether the string is complete

void setup() {
  // initialize serial:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // reserve 200 bytes for the inputString:
  inputString.reserve(200);
}

void loop() {
  // print the string when a newline arrives:
  if (stringComplete) {
    Serial.println(inputString);
    // clear the string:
    inputString = "";
    stringComplete = false;
  }
}

/*
  SerialEvent occurs whenever a new data comes in the
 hardware serial RX.  This routine is run between each
 time loop() runs, so using delay inside loop can delay
 response.  Multiple bytes of data may be available.
 */
void serialEvent() {
  while (Serial.available()) {
    // get the new byte:
    char inChar = (char)Serial.read();
    // add it to the inputString:
    inputString += inChar;
    // if the incoming character is a newline, set a flag
    // so the main loop can do something about it:
    if (inChar == '\n') {
      stringComplete = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong? Nothing. The code is ok the hardware is ok. Serial.available() returns the number of characters in the buffer waiting to be read, so if you don't send it anything it will always return zero/false.

```
int incomingByte = 0;

void setup() {Serial.begin(9600);}

void loop() {
        if (Serial.available() > 0) {
                incomingByte = Serial.read();
                Serial.print("I received: ");
                Serial.println(incomingByte, DEC);
        }
        else Serial.print("I received nothing\n");
        delay(1000);

}
```

Uploading this code and sending 'ss' into the serial buffer will produce:

```
0:00:00.000 -> I received:115 //s
0:00:00.000 -> I received:115 //s
0:00:00.000 -> I received:10  //newline
```

Comment: How did you send the "ss" into the serial buffer?

Comment: @gone: A guess would be from "Serial Monitor", using the "Send" button (menu *"Tools"* → *"Serial Monitor"*). The OP has left the building (*"Last seen more than 1 year ago"*), so we may never know.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved it by including short `delay()` statements. It seems that Arduino reads the first byte and is interrupted with the following...

Comment: I put a `delay(1);` at the end of `if (Serial.available() > 0)` statement, but I don't know if that solves your problem if you tried that `delay()` already...

Comment: didn't work. Thanks though. maybe this will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Some boards restart when a serial connection is initiated. This way when you do `echo smth > /dev/serial/xxxx` board resets, doesn't receive `smth`, and `Serial.available()` never happens.

This behavior can be overridden, or you can communicate with `cat > /dev/serial/xxxx`.

It took me a good while to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Above your code for reading data, insert:

```
if (Serial.available()) {
    int fake = Serial.parseInt();
}
```

This will clear the `0` value returned by the `Serial.available()` function.

Comment: Documentation for [Serial.parseInt()](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/parseint/): *"Looks for the next valid integer in the incoming serial. The function terminates if it times out (see Serial.setTimeout())."*

Comment: What is the gist? To buy some time?

Comment: How does `Serial.parseInt();` get executed if Serial.available() returns 0 (false)? What is the idea? How does this *"clear the 0 value returned by the Serial.available() function"*?

Comment: It *sounds* like a bogus answer. What is the explanation?